# Track canceled facebook login

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-analytics

I wish to track users which were presented with the Facebook Login dialog popup, and chose to close it (by clicking "cancel" or just closed the popup window).

*I am using Facebook SDK and invoking `FB.login()`*

From the [**docs**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0#nonjscancel) it's unclear, but it does appear there might be some way to track this, so, if anyone here knows how, or can help, it would be appriciated. Thanks!

---

### complete code:

```
var facebook = (function(){
    //  Configuration
    var serverDomain = '365scores.com',
        appID        = '158698534219579';

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
        FB.init({
            appId      : appID,
            cookie     : true,  // enable cookies
            xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
            version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(FBLoginStatus);
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', FBLoginStatus);
    };

    function FBLoginStatus(response){
        // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
        // app know the current login status of the person.
        // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
        // for FB.getLoginStatus().
        if( response.status === 'connected' ){
            // Logged into your app and Facebook.
            //connected(response);
            $(document).trigger('connection', ['facebook', response]);
        }
        else if( response.status === 'not_authorized' ){
          // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
        }
        else{
          // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
          // they are logged into this app or not.
        }
    };

    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            FBLoginStatus(response);
        });
    }

    function connected(res){
        console.log( res )
        console.log('FACEBOOK CONENCTED');
        /*
        FB.api('/me', function(response){
        });
        */
    }

    return FBLoginStatus;

})();
```

Comment: Like this? [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
```

Comment: well..kinda. mine is async login

Comment: the answer is also async. "FB.getLoginStatus" is not there to create a login, it´s only there to check if a user is authorized. "FB.login" (like in the answer) is there to actually invoke the login popup.